# Pipenv script cannot find commands ("... could not be found within PATH")

Tags: python, shell, pipenv

## Summary

I cannot execute commands with `pipenv run <some_command_script>`, but whilst in the pipenv shell, I can execute commands successfully.

I don't understand how `pipenv run <some_command_script>` is any different from running `pipenv shell; <some_command_in_the_command_script>`.

### Console Output

#### *via `pipenv run <some command script>`*

```bash
# Commands run via pipenv run fail like so
% pipenv run lint --system
Error: the command black --check . (from lint) could not be found within PATH.
```

#### *via `pipenv shell; <some command>`*

```bash
# Commands run seemingly the exact same way in the pipenv shell run successfully
% pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
 . /Users/clayton/.local/share/virtualenvs/web-personal-fOXGPF80/bin/activate
Fri Aug  5 17:14:42 CEST 2022

% black --check .
All done! ✨  ✨
9 files would be left unchanged.
```

### Pipfile

```ini
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
tornado = ">=6.2"
markdown2 = ">=2.4"
pyyaml = ">=6.0"
pyfiglet = ">=0.8"
colorama = ">=0.4"
gunicorn = ">=20.1"

[dev-packages]
black = "*"
pylint = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"

[scripts]
lint = ["black --check .", "pylint $(git ls-files '*.py')"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the format you should implement looks like the following:

```ini
# Pipfile
[scripts]
lint = "bash -c \"<command_1> ; <command_2> ; <command_3>\""
```

See https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2160 for a closed thread concerning this topic.